# Can a multivalued A record serve as several A records?

Tags: dns

The host (Squarespace) for one of my domains recommends having 4 A records (which they say would have helped in the recent DDoS attack on my registrar) but the tools I have access to for managing my records allow for only a single A record. However it appears that I can enter multiple values in a single A record.

Will a multi-valued A record serve as several A records with single values? Are these equivalent configurations?

Comment: How are "multiple values" entered? Are they delimited somehow? If you enter multiple values and then perform a DNS lookup, what do you see?

Answer (score 2):

*You will find that:*

- A records only support one value per each entry, see: [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035).
- AAAA records only support one value per each entry, see [RFC 3596](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3596#section-2.1).
- Both A and AAAA records support multiple entries.

The issue you have is due to the fact that the name servers and the control panel it uses to config your settings is purposely restricted for one or more reasons, but most often because some registrars, the more expensive type and the ones who like to think they are offering a better service, charge extra for Premium DNS management.

So, without knowing more about the reason you can't add more records your options are:

- Registrar Related Issue
- Contact your current registrar and ask them to manually add the records.
- Contact your current registrar and upgrade to Premium DNS.
- Contact your current registrar and migrate away from them to a better registrar.
- Hosting Related Issue (DNS Records managed by your hosting provider, change of NS records)
- Ask the administrators to manually add the records on your behalf.
- Change name servers and use something like [RackSpace DNS](http://es.rack.ly/cloud/dns) (It's free).

Comment: Agreed (and done). I'll report back what they say (especially why the appear to allow for multi-valeyd A records, and what that means).

Comment: Well it is possible that their control panel has has been simplified and multiple values contained within the value field separated with a character such as `,` equals a separate entry for each... meaning they detect multiple entries and they add multiple records... but the end result would have to be multiple entries, not multiple values.

Comment: Here's what they say: "Adding multiple values is equivalent to associating multiple IP addresses with a single record. It is often used for balancing the load of geographically-distributed web servers. Route 53 allows you to list multiple IP addresses for an “A” record and responds to DNS requests with the list of all configured IP addresses. Route 53 by default would rotate the order of IP addresses in an attempt to share load and there would be no concept of priority. It will randomly resolve the name to one of the IP addresses."

Comment: Here's what they say about entering multiple values: "You can add multiple IPs to “A” record by entering each IP in different line of the value field."